# React Router render components with /:username or /component/

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement a routing structure where a user goes to another user's page or their own when the path is /:username. I also want to render another page with a path /watch or /watch/ .. Facebook has a similar setup where /:username will take you to your page or another user's and /watch/ for example is a page. Is there best practice to achieve this with react-router?

As of now I have something like this..

```
<Route path="/" exact component={authenticated ? Home : Index} />
<Route path="/watch/" component={Watch} />
<Route path="/:username" exact component={({match}) => {
  if(match.params.username === data.Username) {
   return <ProfilePage match={match} />
  } else {
   return <UserPage match={match} />
  }
}} />
```

Now if I got to /watch/ the profile component is being rendered aswell. So :username is going to match all my routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already deducted, `/:username` is matching at the same time as `/watch/` because both patterns match the URL `/watch/`.

Thankfully, React Router provides a [`<Switch>` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) for cases like this one, where only the **first match** is rendered:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/watch/" component={Watch} />
  <Route path="/:username" component={...} />
</Switch>
```

Now, with the URL `/watch/`, only the first route is rendered, even though the second one matches too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **react-router-dom v6**, do these:

1. instead of `Switch`, you should use `Routes`
2. instead of `component={<SomeComponent />}` property, use `element={<SomeComponent />}`

Just in case, you can [Read this article about upgrading from v5 to v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)